# Retrieve XML data from Ajax Prototype

Tags: php, ajax

In a PHP file I parse data from a database ("Chat"), echoing all in XML format. Then, in my index.php file, if I click a button I execute an ajax request to retrieve data from the XML. Why I get a failure? Is correct to echo datas from the query.php file to the index.php file?

query.php

```
#connect to database
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$db_name = "Concerts";

try
{
    $db = new PDO("mysql: host=$servername; dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    die;
}



$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM events");


echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<event>';

foreach ($result as $row)
{
    echo "<title>" . $row['title'] . "</title>";
    echo "<details>" . $row['details'] . "</details>";
    echo "<date>" . $row['date'] . "</date>";
    echo "<place>" . $row['place'] . "</place>";
}

echo "</event>";
?>
```

index.php

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button onclick="myFunc()"> Click </button>


        <script type="text/javascript" src="prototype.js"></script>

        <script>
            function myFunc()
            {
                new Ajax.Request('query.php',
                {
                    method: "get",
                    onSuccess: function(ajax) 
                    { 
                        ajax.getElementsByTagName("title");
                    },
                    onFailure: function() { alert("failure"); },
                    onException: function() { alert("exception"); }
                }
                );
            }
        </script
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The PHP works on its own? `$result` is never used and `$event` is not defined

Comment: Try to learn how to use SimpleXML to build your XML content, it's safer than using a do it yourself method.

Comment: It's better to use json instead of xml.

Comment: with SimpleXML I can't build the string, I need to build it piece by piece, initially putting the introduction, then filling it with a for loop... Doing this, it doesn't work

Comment: SimpleXML is designed to be able to build data dynamically - it would be nearly useless otherwise.